# How to clear the navigation stack so the back button doesn't appear?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift2, uinavigationbar

This is how my view controllers are structured in the storyboard:

```
navController1 -> viewController1 -> viewController2 -> viewController3
```

I have a segue from `viewController3` back to `viewController1`. So, when the user transitions to `viewContoller1`, the back button shows on the navbar (as expected). However, in my case, I don't want the user to go back to `viewController3`, from `viewController1`. I want to start fresh from `viewController1` again. Is there a way to clear the stack after transitioning to `viewController1`, so that the back button does not appear?

(Note that navController1 is not my root controller, I have some other controllers before it.)

Answer (score 0):

You have the navigationController member. It's actually a stack of the pushed in controllers. Clear the stack and you should get the result you want. To do that set an empty list to the navigationController?.viewControllers in your last View Controller. Hope this will help you find a solution.

Comment: There are other times I need the back button to show up on view controller1 though. Only when I travel from viewcontroller3 do I now want the back button. So can I apply your code in the prepareForSegue method in viewcontroller3?

Comment: You can modify the stacks as you like when you are in the View Controller. The stack can be emptied but also modified (for example,if you have 4 view controllers, you can remove 2 of them).If you need more complex situations you should start from my hint and try. Keep in mind that you have also 2 lists for the right and left buttons of the navigation controller. You can add and remove buttons from those lists too.

Comment: Thanks. How can I tell in viewController1, that I came from viewController3? Sorry, I'm pretty new to Swift.

Comment: No problem :-) ... In the stack I mentioned earlier you can remove the viewControllers that you don't need anymore. For example, if you have in the stack vc1, vc2, vc3 and vc4, you can remove from the stack navigationController?.viewControllers vc2 and vc3, so, when you'll hit the back button from vc4, you'll go back directly to vc1, skipping vc2 and vc3. If you use a storyboard then you need a slightly different solution... but it doesn't look your case though.

Comment: I tried a few things but with no luck. If I remove all viewcontrollers, my whole navigation bar disappears. I also tried removeLast(), that throws an error when I transition. Anyway you can show me some code on how I can hide the back button when (and only when) I got to viewcontroller1 from viewcontroller3?

Comment: ummm.. strange.I'll post you some code. But I need to write it before. Here it's quite late (I'm in Europe), but I'm going to check it tomorrow and I'll post you some more hints and the code.

Comment: Are you using a storyboard?